# How to enforce LI formatting in a contenteditable UL

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm trying to allow users to edit a list (UL). In my attempts, it appears that contenteditable doesn't do anything special (like enforcing behind-the-scenes markup) -- it just gives the user a window into the innerHTML.

This is causing issues in that if there is not already a LI, and the user adds something, it doesn't get LI-ized. Similarly, if there are list items, but the user deletes them, then the LI gets deleted, and any new text is added without LI's. See http://jsfiddle.net/JTWSC/ . I've also found that it's sometimes possible for the cursor to "get outside" of an LI that does exist, but I can't reproduce consistently.

I have to include code, so this is what the "result" looks like:

```
<ul>whatever the user typed in</ul>
```

How do I fix this? I started down the path of a $('ul').keyup() handler that checks the html and wraps as necessary, but I was running into a handful of gotchas, like timing, losing focus on the element, having to refocus in the right place, etc. I'm sure it's possible if I work at it, but I'm hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: Consider using a "markdown editor" as StackOverflow does instead. Making a smart-enough WYSIWYG editor is a huge and complex problem.

Comment: Markdown (or wysiwyg) plugins are my absolute last resorts. My users aren't *nearly* as sophisticated as SO's, and I basically want to limit input to plain text (the reason I'm using div.contenteditable vs textarea is so that I can auto-style the text with stuff like ::first-line and include lists, which is an absolute requirement).

Comment: Sadly, means running real-time HTML validation and throwing errors and expecting users to know what the errors mean. Time is better spent in training than trying to make the software "idiot proof".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I built the following keyup/down handler in order to make my contenteditable <UL>s idiot proof.*

It does two things:

1. Adds <LI>s to the <UL> when the <UL> is empty. I use some code I found on SO (from Tim Down) to place the caret in the expected place
2. Cleans up all non-LI / non-BR tags. This is basically a quick-and-dirty paste-cleaner.

This is pushing my comfort-level on jquery and DOM manipulation, so there are probably a few things I could do better, but it works pretty well as-is.

```
//keyup prevented the user from deleting the bullet (by adding one back right after delete), but didn't add in li's on empty ul's, thus keydown added to check
$('ul').on('keyup keydown', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
    if (! $this.html()) {
        var $li = $('&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
        var sel = window.getSelection();
       var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.insertNode($li.get(0));
        range = range.cloneRange();
        range.selectNodeContents($li.get(0));
        range.collapse(false);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

    } else {
        //are there any tags that AREN'T LIs?
        //this should only occur on a paste
        var $nonLI = $this.find(':not(li, br)');

        if ($nonLI.length) {
            $this.contents().replaceWith(function() {
    //we create a fake div, add the text, then get the html in order to strip out html code. we then clean up a bit by replacing nbsp's with real spaces
return '&lt;li&gt;' + $('&lt;div /&gt;').text($(this).text()).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ') + '</li>';
            });
            //we could make this better by putting the caret at the end of the last LI, or something similar
        }                   
    }
});
```

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/aVuEk/5/

*I respectfully disagree with Diodeus that training is the best / easiest solution in all cases. In my situation, I have several contenteditable <UL>s on a page that are *very* in-line WYSIWYG (ie, not a lot of room for tinymce-style chrome) and used by casual, first-time, non-advanced users.

Comment: I had a problem with the posted [jsfiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/aVuEk/5/).  In Firefox (v26.0+??), when I press backspace on an empty list, a `<br/>` is inserted above the `<ul>`.  A partial solution is to use a `<div>` inside the `<ul>` for editing, along with a few other tricks.  See the full solution at http://jsfiddle.net/aVuEk/38/.  There is one bug noted in the comments that could not be resolved simply.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention.  There is another problem when the entire text is selected and deleted.  This causes the last remaining `<li>` to be removed.  A few modifications to the first `if` statement resolve the problem. The modifications are include in http://jsfiddle.net/aVuEk/38/.

Comment: Hmm. How (in)valid is `<ul><div><li></li></div></ul>`?

Comment: I agree the resulting `<ul><div><li></li></div></ul>` is quite hackish.  But none of the major web browsers seem to complain about it, and it resolves an otherwise difficult-to-fix bug.